# React Child Props not being Passed down

Tags: reactjs

I'm about to have a meltdown having tried to solve this problem for three days now. I can't seem to get the child component of my react-route to receive the props being passed to it. Instead it is rendering with them as undefined.

**The flow is as follows:**

```
submitFile -> (Callback) -> App (set state using useState hooks) -> Dashboard
```

I've checked and the callback is working properly so the data is coming back to the App and console.log confirms that the state has been set. However I really don't understand why the Dashboard component is being created with props as undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried some many different things and read numerous threads and docs and I'm frankly about to explode!

**Please see the code below:
App.js**

```
export default function App() {
    const [authState, setState] = useState(false);
    const [jobId, setJobId] = useState(false);
    const [token, setToken] = useState(false);
    const [apiKey, setApiKey] = useState(false);

    const authCallbackState = authStateData => {
        setState(authStateData);
    };

    const jobCallback = (jobId_, token_, apiKey_) => {
        setJobId(jobId_);
        setToken(token_);
        setApiKey(apiKey_);
    };

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route
                        path="/dashboard"
                        render={() =>
                            authState && apiKey ? (
                                <Dashboard jobId={jobId} token={token} apiKey={apiKey} />
                            ) : (
                                <h1>loading</h1>
                            )
                        }
                    ></Route>
                    <PrivateRoute path="/submitFile" authState={authState}>
                        <CssBaseline />
                        <SubmitFile dbCallback={jobCallback} />
                    </PrivateRoute>
                    <Route path="/">
                        <AuthComponent appCallback={authCallbackState} />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

As you can see I've made it so the dashboard only renders once the switch is made in the link, at the very least the values should be false not undefined?

**Dashboard function that uses the props**

```
export default function Dashboard(props) {

    /**
     * Polls the API at 30 second intervals to check job status
     *
     */
    const getFile = async e => {
        const url = baseUrl + '/get_results';
        const headers = { headers: { 'x-api-key': props.apiKey, Authorization: props.token } };
        console.log(headers['Authorization']);
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            axios.get(url, props.jobId, headers).then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    setProgress(100);
                    showWaitMessage(false);
                    setFile(response.data);
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
                if (response.status === 202) {
                    if (progress < 100) {
                        setProgress(progress + 10);
                    } else if (!ackWaitMessage) {
                        showWaitMessage(true);
                    }
                }
                if (response.status === 403) {
                    // show some error message
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }enter code here
                if (response.status === 400 || 404) {
                    showErrorMessage(true);
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            });
        }, 30000);
    };
```

Comment: Can't say for sure but seems like setInterval has some closure and won't take care of the props changing. Maybe try with a useInterval hook. Here is an example of it : https://github.com/donavon/use-interval/blob/master/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` gets a closure and polls with the same props every time.

You can use `useEffect` hook to update your polling function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const watcher = setInterval(....);
    return () => clearInterval(watcher);
}, [props.jobId, props.token, props.apiKey]);
```

Or you can store your current props inside `useRef`:

```
const propsRef = useRef(props);
propsRef.current = props;
```

And access them as `propsRef.current.jobId` inside `getFile`

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry to have wasted everyones time. I thought I was being clever previously when I had the following useEffect in the child component:

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.jobId);
        getFile();
    }, []);
```

Which obviously locked in the state of the child due to the empty dependency array. DOH!

I have updated it to be

````
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.jobId);
        getFile();
    }, [props.jobId, props.apiKey, props.token]);```

and it works fine.
````